# <textarea> not expanding when using \n as newline

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code for an Autocomplete input that will add to a textarea element the value that is choosen on the Autocomplete input, as a list seperated by new row.

When adding rows to the textarea seperatly, by pressing Enter for a new row, it expands to fill in the new row and value, however, in my case, when using +('\n') a new line is created but the textarea is not expanding. I guess that it got to do with the functionality of Enter vs \n. So is there a different way to create a newline that textarea will also expand?

My code snippet is:

```
b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          document.getElementById('myTxt').focus();
          document.getElementById('myInput').focus();
          myTxt.value += this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value + ('\n');
          inp.value = "";
```

Comment: What is the styling on the textarea field? Could you add a minimal example to evaluate?

Comment: using bootstrap form control for <textarea> https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

- `\r = CR (Carriage Return) → Used as a new line character in Mac OS before X`
- `\n = LF (Line Feed) → Used as a new line character in Unix/Mac OS X`
- `\r\n = CR + LF → Used as a new line character in Windows`

Comment: All are working with creating a newline for me, but not with expanding the textarea

Comment: What about `&#10;`  and `&#13;` ? In some cases you need to combine them `&#13;&#10;`